# Debug object names from GHC

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, object-files

My program compiled by GHC crashes*, and `gdb` shows that the calling function has the name `s10kL_info`. Is it possible show the human-readable function name, or at least the human-readable name of a function above `s10kL_info`, maybe by letting GHC write debug symbols to the object file?

<sub>* (my crash is probably caused by using foreign libraries or unsafe IO functions)</sub>

Comment: I know of no way to map such auto-generated symbols to function names. You could perhaps try to recompile and dump the core and assembly, `-ddump-simpl -ddump-asm -ddump-to-file`, then it should be possible (though tedious) to map the symbols to code.